# Oracle 12g Weblogic server MEDREC WADL

Tags: oracle, rest, weblogic12c, wadl

I'm trying to setup an API test suite using SoapUI (or any other similar software) with a oracle Linux Weblogic 12g server MEDREC sample app.
The problem is that i cannot find anywhere the WADL mapping for the REST API calls.

i've tried in the oracle website but there is no reference to WADL mapping there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a WADL and a WSDL maps:
can be accessed through:
Oracle Admin Console--> Deployments--> medrec--> Testing
there you can find the WADL and WSDL under medrec app tree